# How to return distinct rows meeting condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an example table in the format below with sample data:

=cust_table

```
Customer:  Liked_Color:
Adam       Blue    
Adam       Green    
Adam       Yellow    
Adam       Red    
Bob        Yellow    
Bob        Yellow    
Bob        Yellow    
Bob        Yellow    
Charlie    Red    
Charlie    Red    
Charlie    Red    
Charlie    Red
```

How can I select distinct customers and only return them if they DO NOT like the color Blue?

So, the returned results would be:

Customer: Bob, Charlie

If I do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Customer
FROM cust_table
WHERE Liked_Color NOT LIKE Blue
```

I get: Adam, Bob, Charlie

How would I make sure the Customer is only returned when Blue is not a Liked_Color for a Customer?

Comment: Why did you ruin the nice formatting?

Answer (score 1):

I would use aggregation:

```
select customer
from cust_table
group by customer
having sum(case when color = 'Blue' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

However, a `customer` table should have one row per customer (at least per unit time).  If you had such a table and a `customer_colors` table, then I would use `not exists`:

```
select c.*
from customers c
where not exists (select 1
                  from customer_colors cc
                  where cc.customer = c.customer and cc.color = 'Blue'
                 );
```

This would also return customers with no preferred color at all, which you cannot do with your single table.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, see whether sets do any good:

```
SQL> with cust (customer, liked_color) as
  2    (select 'Adam'   , 'Blue'   from dual union all
  3     select 'Adam'   , 'Green'  from dual union all
  4     select 'Bob'    , 'Yellow' from dual union all
  5     select 'Bob'    , 'Red'    from dual union all
  6     select 'Charlie', 'Red'    from dual union all
  7     select 'Charlie', 'Red'    from dual
  8    )
  9  select customer from cust where liked_color <> 'Blue'
 10  minus
 11  select customer from cust where liked_color = 'Blue';

CUSTOME
-------
Bob
Charlie

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work the simplest of them all :

```
select distinct a from Table1 where a not in 
(select distinct a from Table1 where b like 'Blue');
```

check fiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7034f/10